# Disproving the existence of a limit using the epsilon delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I wanted to disprove the existence of limit;
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x} $$
I proved it in the following way.
Let us suppose to the contrary that the limit exists.
We consider 2 cases.

**(i)** $L≠0$
Let $ε=L/4.$
$0<|x|<δ ⇒ |(1/x)-L| < L/4$,
Let $x=1/(2L)$ such that $$0<|1/2L|<δ 
⇒ |2L-L|<L/4 ⇒ |L|<L/4,$$

which is a contradiction.

**(ii)** $L=0.$
Let $ε=1.$
$0<|x|<δ ⇒ |(1/x)| < 1$,
Let $x=1/2$ such that $$0<|1/2|<δ   
 ⇒ |2|<1,$$
which is a contradiction.
Hence the existance of limit is disproved.

I am new to advanced mathematics and mathematical proofs. I don't know whether this proof is correct or not. It would be helpful if someone could verify whether this is correct and, if not, could point out the mistakes.
Thank you.

Comment: Please typeset this in MathJax. For example `$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*answer for case **(i)***

Choose $\epsilon = \frac{|L|}{4}.$
I do not think you are free to assume $\frac1{|2L|}<\delta$, but we can do something similar. We may choose $x>0$ such that both $0<x<\delta$ and $0<x<\frac1{|2L|}$ hold, or written together, $$0<x<\min\left(\delta,\frac1{|2L|}\right).$$

From our epsilon-delta implication, we may now write
$$\left|\frac1x\right| - \left|L\right| \leq \left|\frac1x - L\right|<\frac{|L|}4,$$

$$0<\frac1x   \leq  \frac{5|L|}4,$$

$$0< \frac4{5|L|}  \leq  x < \frac1{2|L|}.$$
This last relation is not possible.

*hint for case **(ii)***

Your proof for the second case is flawed in the same way as your proof for the first case, but you can fix it in the same way: by choosing your positive $x$ to satisfy two inequalities simultaneously.

Comment: Could you please clarify why we can't assume 1/|2L|<δ

Comment: Yes I will try to clarify. Think of *the definition of "the limit of $f(x)$ exists at $x=0.$"* We are invited to choose any positive epsilon. Since the limit exists, we are guaranteed a positive delta, in response to our epsilon. (*Good so far?*) But we know nothing about the magnitude of delta - we only know it is positive. Now in your logic, the same is true about $|L|$ - we know nothing about its magnitude, we only know it is positive. So we don't know which is true: $$\frac1{|2L|}< \delta,$$ or $$\frac1{|2L|} \geqslant \delta.$$

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Got it.